# Connecting to Ubuntu via SSH throw third Windows server

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, rdp

So. I have 3 servers.

server #1 — is my local Macbook.

server #2 — is my office Windows Server, to which I can access only by RDP with username/password, with enabled VPN connection on my Macbook.

server #3 — is Ubuntu Virtual Machine, running on #2 server on VMWARE workstation. It's under NAT and shares the host's IP address in the network, and doesn't have access from the public. And I have full access to it from server #2. There are running SSH server and I can connect to it via SSH from server #2.

I haven't access to router, and can't change anything in the network.

Question: how to connect to Ubuntu (#3 server) from my Macbook (#1 server) via console and SSH, using all of this?

Comment: You might be able to make an SSH connection from #2 to #3 including a port forward from some other port on #2 to the SSH port on #3 (or any equivalent port-forward tool), and #1 might be able to connect to that port on #2. However that might be blocked by the firewall on #2 if you can't configure that.

Comment: ssh -J user1@host1:port1 user2@host2:port2 check the [link](https://www.tecmint.com/access-linux-server-using-a-jump-host/) for the further details.